# SlimPicker doesn't work with jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, html, mootools

I want jQuery and slimpicker work together, what should I do?:
[Sample from http://jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/MyNameIsCode/ZRGAd/2/)

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.styledisplay.com/scripts/slimpicker/pagestyle.css" media="screen, projection" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.styledisplay.com/scripts/slimpicker/slimpicker.css" media="screen, projection" />
    <script src="http://www.styledisplay.com/scripts/slimpicker/mootools-1.2.4-core-yc.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.styledisplay.com/scripts/slimpicker/mootools-1.2.4.4-more-yc.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.styledisplay.com/scripts/slimpicker/slimpicker.js"></script>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#button").click(function () {
                alert("I'm inside jQuery function!");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <h1>SlimPicker</h1>
    <div class="intro">
        <p>Date Picker that works in IFrames. Also allows for keyboard navigation.</p>
    </div>
    <p>
        <label for="new_day">default calendar</label>
        <input id="new_day" name="new_day" type="text" class="slimpicker" autocomplete="off" value="" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="birthday">calendar with options</label>
        <input id="birthday" name="birthday" type="text" class="slimpicker" autocomplete="off" alt="{
            dayChars:3,
            dayNames:['Sonntag', 'Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'Freitag', 'Samstag'],
            daysInMonth:[31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31],
            format:'yyyy-mm-dd',
            monthNames:['Januar', 'Februar', 'M&auml;rz', 'April', 'Mai', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'August', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'Dezember'],
            startDay:1,
            yearOrder:'desc',
            yearRange:90,
            yearStart:2007
        }" value="1980-03-13" />
    </p>
    <p>
        This button uses <strong>jquery-1.7.2.min.js plugin</strong>
        <input type="button" id="button" value="Click me" style="{text-align:center}"/>
        <br />
        To activate calendar, remove this reference from the code <br />
            <strong>http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js</strong>

    </p>
</div>
<script>
    $$('input.slimpicker').each( function(el){
        var picker = new SlimPicker(el);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get it to work easily. The problem here is that SlimPicker is old and does not adhere to mootools codex - i.e. it still uses $ in preference to `document.id`.

you can fix it by creating a closure around the class: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/ZRGAd/9/

in code it's like:

```
(function($) {
var SlimPicker = this.SlimPicker = new Class({
    method: function() {
        console.log($ == jQuery); // false
    }
});
}(document.id));
console.log($ == jQuery); // true
```

or, search and replace all `$()` references in the class with `document.id`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken. Both mootools and jQuery uses `$` for shorthand for their main functions. Hence you get a collision.

I would look in to [jQuery noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Also I tried removing all the jQuery code from your jsFiddle and it still throws a lot of errors. Don't know mootools, but try to fixes the error then add jQuery with the noConflict.

Comment: Yes. If I try to remove jQuery plug in, slimpicker will work properly.