# Javascript conflict with datepicker and ajax form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this script which i need in order to use a datepicker and to submit a form through ajax.
The issue is, the datepicker won't work if there are the javascripts of the ajax form..
How can i solve it, i founf smth about jquery no conflict, but either i didn't know how to use it, or it won't solve my problem..

Thanks!

```
<script src="../js/mootools-1.2.4-core-yc.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/mootools-1.2.4.4-more-yc.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/slimpicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {


});
</script>
```

Comment: I found the answer here for anyone who's interested:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103544/slimpicker-doesnt-work-with-jquery-plugin

Comment: i tried to do that, but ut goes as a comment..